# Inserir uma data na base de dados através de jquery+php

Tags: php, html, jquery, sql

Tenho um datepicker assim

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />

    <form action="dashboard.php" name="form1" class="form1" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="dtSelectorStatic" />

    </form>
</li>
```

E uma script assim:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#dtSelectorStatic").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
    (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
    (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day;

    $("#dtSelectorStatic").datepicker("setDate", new Date(output));

    console.log(output);

    $('#dtSelectorStatic').on('change', function() {
        console.log('Submiting form');
        console.log(output);
        $('#form1').submit();

    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Tenho uma função para inserir todos os dados na base de dados e preciso de passar este valor da datepicker para a função de inserir

Nota: O código encontra-se todo na mesma página .php

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer

Comment: os inputs precisam da tag `name` para serem identificados pelo script PHP

Comment: Quero usar a variavel "output" que contém a data escolhida pelo utilizador para depois ao carregar no botão de inserir, ele inserir na base de dados todas as informações mais a data, porém não consigo usar essa tal variavel "output" no php da mesma página

Answer (score 0):

Ainda não entendi por que não usar um:

```
<input type="date" name="data" id="dtSelectorStatic">

<script>
$("#dtSelectorStatic").change(function(){
$("#form1").submit()
});
</script>
```

Se o que você quer é submeter um formulário com a alteração de uma data aí está a sua resposta, caso não explique melhor.

Comment: Caso seu erro esteja no PHP ou no DML adicione as informações na sua pergunta!

Comment: O problema é usar a variável "output" da função para outra função em php que eu tenho na mesma página para fazer a inserção na base de dados

Comment: independente de estar nas mesma página ou não, se você quer enviar um dado de um formulário para uma função PHP você tem que submeter o formulário para a página php salvar este dado em uma variável e enviar esse dado como parâmetro para a função!

Comment: conte mais abertamente como o programa deve funcionar talvez o que você queira fazer deste jeito tenha uma solução mais simples.

Answer (score -1):

Você já adicionou a parte que faz a requisição? Que é isso que não estou vendo.

Executando o seu código. Percebi que a data vem no formato "Brasileiro". Que é o formato que representa, respectivamente: dd/mm/YYYY.

Será que o campo que receberá a data, no banco de dados, esta com esse mesmo padrão (dd/mm/YYYY), ou ele estão no padrão "YYYY-mm-dd"?

Dependendo de como esse valor será armazenado no banco de dados, você tem que converter para tal.

Confira na descrição dos campos da tabela qual o formato de dados aceito. Daí é só converter para ele (se for do tipo Date, na padrão YYYY-mm-dd).

Abraços!

Comment: Sim e em Portugal usamos esse método, dia/mês/ano e quero que o utilizador use essa mesma maneira, na função de adicionar o registo eu converto a data com o seguinte código:
$_SESSION['data'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_SESSION['data']));
Porém eu tenho de ir buscar a data à função a cima referida para usar na função de inserir

Comment: Bem, ainda faltam algumas peças. Experimente colocar aqui todas as peças que compõe o fluxo do cadastro da data. Digo isto, pois, deve ter algum detalhe que está no seu arquivo de inserção e a tabela do banco de dados. Faz o seguinte: veja se o valor que esta tentando cadastrar esta realmente chegando na página do script de inserção. Faz na calma e devagar. Se possível anota no papel o fluxo de como deve ser essa inserção de registro. No meio do caminho encontrará a solução. Ou então coloca todos os fragmentos de códigos para poder analisar melhor. Abraços!

Comment: Acho que não há erro nenhum, só queria saber se há alguma maneira de eu passar a variável "output" da função pois ela fica com o valor da data que eu quero para a tal função em php que faz a inserção. Não sei como posso mandar a variável de um jquery para php

Comment: Comentei sem querer aqui, Vou comentar mais embaixo...

Comment: Se você quer fazer isso na mesma página. Esquece. Caso contrário, o valor da sua variável output estará disponível no corpo de alguma dessas requisiçoes: GET, POST, PUT ou DELETE.